# Attitude toward a sinner

Tags: sharia, hadith

I know when a person commit a sin he/she should be punished. And Muslim should not feel mercy when the punishment is give to them. Now there are many sin when a person he/she did't get punished.

So There are two types of sinner now:

1. Who grieve on his/her sin
2. Person who proudly tells everyone

I am not talking about the first type. I want to talk about the second type of person.

**How should we treat a person who don't feel shame in his/her sin?**

reply in the view of Islam.

Comment: How close is that person to you? family?

Comment: @AmericanMuslim no i was talking generally. I have some friend.

Answer (score 1):

a sinner must be treated with kindness in order to win his heart over ,beware of treating them badly ,because we are all sinners after all ,and we wouldn't like people to be rude with us, so treat them kindly, advise them privatly that what they are doing is wrong, do not expose them even if they are exposing themselves, because may be they are ignorants of what they are doing, do Nassiha, be kind , smile always  :) !!

Comment: Salaam, and welcome to Islam.SE. As is case with every other SE site, we expects answers here to be substantial and backed up by relevant (in this Islamic) sources. Please consider improving your answer, and also have a look at [How do I write good answers](http://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

Its a greater sin every one should hide his sin and repent to Allah Azzawajal

Doing sin and telling with other without feeling bad about the sin is called as Mujahara in Islam and its a greater sin.

Please stop him doing so.

Explain him about this. See below video

https://www.facebook.com/video.php?v=631028787014165

Comment: yes but what should our attitude toward him/her.